# Do any denominations believe in reincarnation?

Tags: denomination-survey, nature-of-man, reincarnation

In discussion with others about God's will in situations that don't have any answers (i.e. - difficult prolonged situations) I hear a lot of (as also mentioned in [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17666/what-are-christians-trusting-god-about-when-in-fallen-world-circumstance) and answer) that God is "teaching us lessons and preparing us for eternity".

However, when I put this together with the fact that humans are in all different stages of learning lessons (some almost barely getting by - to some here on vacation on this earth), sayings like "she is an old soul" and the fact that some people don't need to learn certain lessons, they just "have it" from birth, there is a chance after death for atonement - I logically, instinctively and intuitively get the feeling that souls are reincarnated and purified to be more like the light of Christ, through each human experience they occupy.

I have heard there are other religions that believe this but independently of them, are there any Chrisitian denominations that also believe this? Why or why not is it valid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Isn't reincarnation affirmed by the Bible?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/isnt-reincarnation-affirmed-by-the-bible)

Comment: Scriptural ly, there is no case to be made, as that one shows. I realize you are asking if any do- I can pretty unequivocally state that if one onscure sect did, the other 99.99% would be quick to say they heretics.

Comment: This is a list question. It is hard enough to get a list of all the Christian groups out there. This question then asks us to sort them by what they believe. In short, no answer can every be called complete, and the negative answer saying none cannot be proven.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Source:** Morse, D. R. (2006, April). Reincarnation: Yes, No or Maybe!. *Journal of Spirituality & Paranormal Studies*. p. 61.

> Although some sects of Christianity accept reincarnation, for some
>   people (e.g., innocent infants, murder victims), generally,
>   Christianity does not support reincarnation, because no matter how
>   evil you might have been, if you repent and accept Jesus Christ as the
>   Son of God and your savior, you will go on to Heaven.

**Source:** Davies, M. (2004). Should Christianity Embrace Mediumship, Healing and Reincarnation?. *Journal Of Religion & Psychical Research*, 27(3), 132-144.

> St Paul very plainly rejects reincarnation in his letter to the Hebrews. (Hebrews 9:27-28)
>
> The Gnostics did believe in reincarnation, but they were squashed
>   after the Council at Nicaea in 325 AD.
>
> St. Jerome tells us that metempsychosis (reincarnation) was a secret
>   doctrine of certain sects in his day, but it was too evidently opposed
>   to the Catholic doctrine of Redemption ever to obtain a settled
>   rooting.
>
> However some sects — particularly the early Gnostics and the later
>   Cathars of 13th century France — did believe in reincarnation, and
>   often paid the price.
>
> While some individual Christians believe in reincarnation, the only
>   major push for reincarnation from within official Christian circles
>   has been from the "Army of Mary," a Catholic sect that is based in
>   Quebec, Canada.

**Conclusion:**

Although there are certainly Christian individuals and sects that accept reincarnation, reincarnation has always been an iffy issue, because it has long been perceived to undermine the significance of the sacrificial death of Jesus Christ. There are examples of such sects, as mentioned above. Sects who do believe in this reincarnation are often persecuted, and over the centuries, the non-heretics procreate non-heretic offspring, which is why the number of people who believes in reincarnation is in the minority.

Comment: @anonymous: thanks for the info, that is really informative, of all the sects to believe in it I can't believe it is Catholic. I wonder how they got to that conclusion?

Comment: Try asking *that* question on the Christianity.SE next time!

Answer (score 4):

> "I logically, instinctively and intuitively get the feeling that souls
>   are reincarnated and purified to be more like the light of Christ,
>   through each human experience they occupy. "
>
> "The heart is deceitful above all things, And desperately wicked; Who
>   can know it? (Jeremiah 17:9)

Just a warning, you're instincts and feelings can betray you :).  The truth is

> "And as it is appointed for men to die once, but after this the
>   judgment" (Hebrews 9:27)

There are no denominations that support reincarnation to my knowledge, for it goes against the Bible.  May the Lord bless you as you study His word.

Comment: You may have an interesting quote there, but can you cite where you got it from?

Comment: @pterandon: The quote "I logically, instinctively and intuitively get the feeling that souls are reincarnated and purified to be more like the light of Christ, through each human experience they occupy. " is found in the original question post. The other two verses are cited from the Bible.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Update the Gnostics based on another answer did believe in reincarnation, (although some denominations consider Gnostics not exactly Christian).  Thanks for the answer Anonymous my knowledge has increased :)

Answer (score 3):

this sounds a lot like the `Nature Vs. Nurture` argument to me.

just because someone has wisdom beyond their years doesn't mean that they magically got it from a previous life.  I believe that they did sort of get it from a previous life, from their upbringing. I am good with logic and Mathematics, but that is because of the way that my Father talked to me and explained things to me. these things are true for everyone. motivation and patience and other things like that are learned through the years, during vital times of development.

there is no way for those that are Dead to come back to Learn more, if they have not Learned it the first time then they are forever lost. as illustrated when Lazarus was with Abraham.

[Luke 16:19-31](http://biblia.com/books/esv/Lk16.19)

Verse 26

```
And besides all this, between us and you a great chasm has been fixed, 
in order that those who would pass from here to you may not be able, 
and none may cross from there to us.
```