# What about the "beforelife"?

Tags: nature-of-man

It is a common concern in all humans to know about the afterlife, but what do religions say about the *beforelife*? Some religions say reincarnation, and I think the vast majority of the rest just takes the subject very tangentially (since practically nothing is said about this too publicly). I would include the Christianity that is commonly taught in this category, since I don't think there is a public (non-academic, at least) discussion about this.

### What does the Bible say about this?

Comment: I know that the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-Day Saints has a strong opinion on what you call the "beforelife". They call it "pre-existence". It's a core part of Mormon theology.

Comment: Related: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/18378/20

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted.  It could use some rewording, but the question appears reasonable.  Just because a question is "obvious" to you, doesn't mean you should downvote someone else's question.  What ever happened to, "the only stupid question is the one not asked?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bible is absolutely silent about any "before life" other than [Jeremiah 1:5](http://biblehub.com/jeremiah/1-5.htm), which says God knew us even when we were in our mother's Womb.  that doesn't speak so much about our "before life" as God's Omniscience.

The LDS Church teaches about the "[Premortal existence](http://lds.about.com/od/basicsgospelprinciples/p/pre-existence.htm)" but that's a doctrine unique to them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, David. I think I will just have to wonder about it the rest of my life, making really dumb and useless personal(no offenses to anyone except me) theories about it :)

Comment: Most Christian denominations teach that there explicitly is no "beforelife," in part based on the verse in this answer. They consider creation/formation to be when the person comes into existence; not just the body.

Comment: Catholicism is also similar, @Flimzy, saying that all souls are specially created when a mortal body is made ready for them.

Comment: @David Stratton:: one commentary on ps.139:16 says: "...not only each of the members of the body were put down in this book, but each of the days in which they should be formed and come into order..." and all this before even one day was lived.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you seem to be asking if our Souls and Spirits existed before birth of the human body?

If I misunderstand I apologize, but if my assumption is correct I wish to point out a few Scriptures which may help you to come to a conclusion about that, but first let me point out that that question as I have understood it is really asking did man 's Souls exist before their creation.

To believe that would to elevate man to the same status as God, in that the Soul would have no beginning and no end, and we must be careful in that area as it was the reason Satan was expelled from Heaven.

We have a definite answer to that in  Genesis;

Genesis 2:7  KJV

> And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his >nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.

To believe that man's Soul existed prior to God creating man is contrary to what Genesis 2:7 states.

If the first man became a living soul when he received the breath of life we have no reason to believe that any other human would be  any different.

Also two of the major prophets have stated that God creates everyone in the mother's womb.

Isaiah 44:2, & 24  KJV

> 2  Thus saith the LORD that made thee, and formed thee from the womb, which will >help thee; Fear not, O Jacob, my servant; and thou, Jesurun, whom I have chosen.
>
> 24 Thus saith the LORD, thy redeemer, and he that formed thee from the womb, I am the LORD that maketh all things; that stretcheth forth the heavens alone; that spreadeth abroad the earth by myself;

Isaiah 49:5 KJV

> And now, saith the LORD that formed me from the womb to be his servant, to bring >Jacob again to him, Though Israel be not gathered, yet shall I be glorious in the eyes of >the LORD, and my God shall be my strength.

Also in Jeremiah it states that God created man in the womb.

Jeremiah 1:5 KJV

> Before I formed thee in the belly I knew thee; and before thou camest forth out of the womb I sanctified thee, and I ordained thee a prophet unto the nations.

If you do believe that the Bible is God's word, as I do; it would behoove you to tread lightly in this area.

Comment: 1. `it is really asking did man 's Souls exist before creation` That's not true at all. Human spirits could have existed prior to birth/conception, without existing prior to creation.
2. `To believe that would to elevate man to the same status as God` That also doesn't follow logically.

Comment: @http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/20/flimsy Sorry I did not make myself clear, but what I meant was that did man 's Souls exist before THEIR creation. Also if those Souls did always exist they would not just have eternal life, but would therefore be Infinite in that they would have no beginning and would also have no end. That is true only of God.

Comment: @ http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/20/flimsy Thank you for pointing out my errors I have edited my answer in view of your comments

Comment: It's better, but there's still no reason to think that "the Soul would have no beginning and no end".  God could create the soul prior to the body; that in no way implies the soul is eternal.

Comment: @ http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/20/flimzy as I read Genesis it does not say that God created the Soul it says that when God breathed the breath of life into man he became a living soul which to me seems to say that the Breath of life is 1. Eternal and immortal. 2. was the basis for the formation of the Soul. 3. the breath of life is a living part of the Creator God. Please correct me if that in any way conflicts with the Bible.

Comment: 1. You are making several claims without providing references. 2. There are multiple concepts and words which translate into the English word "soul". I don't think any of them are believed to be "eternal" in the sense of having neither a beginning nor end, according to most Christian doctrine.

Comment: @http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/20/flimsy If you prefer we can continue this in e-mail My address is cbeckum@nctv.com